# Evaluation with CNTKlibrary.h in C++ Project

Tags: c++, cntk

I have trained my model with BrainScript and now want to use it in a C++ project. From the [EvalMultithreads.cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/Evaluation/CNTKLibraryCPPEvalCPUOnlyExamples/EvalMultithreads.cpp) I copied all the relevant functions. I linked the CNTK.Core and CNTK.Math library and set their search path as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Library-Evaluation-on-Linux). Of course I included the CNTKLibrary.h.
When I build the project the compiler gives me this error:

> undefined reference to `CNTK::Variable::Name[abi:cxx11]() const'

It referrers to this line :

```
if (it->Name().compare(varName) == 0)
```

of the EvalMultithreads.cpp function bool GetVariableByName, and also :

> undefined reference to `CNTK::Function::LoadModel(std::__cxx11::basic_string CMakeFiles/xxx.dir/build.make:1848: recipe for target '/home/path/xxx.exe' failed
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/xxx.dir/all' failed
>   Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed

Does anyone had the same troubles?

FYI: I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04`, `gcc` version `5.4.0`, CNTK ver2.0rc2 GPU with 1-bit SGD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CNTK.Core and other libraries in the binary release package are compiled with GCC 4.8, so they cannot be directly linked with application using gcc 5.4.0. Please use the same build flavor (Debug/Release) and [the same compiler version](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-CNTK-on-Linux#c-compiler) as the one used to create the libraries, as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Library-Evaluation-on-Linux).
If you want to use gcc 5.4.0, you need to build the library from source.